# Order Dataframe by vector while preserving indices

Tags: r, sorting, vector, dataframe

Let's say I have this data frame named **result**:

```
  id nobs
1 25  463
2 26  586
3 27  338
4 28  475
5 29  711
6 30  932
```

and this vector:

```
ord = c(30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25)
```

Now I understand that I can order the data frame according to the vector ord by doing this:

```
result[match(ord, result$id),]
```

to get the following result:

```
  id nobs
6 30  932
5 29  711
4 28  475
3 27  338
2 26  586
1 25  463
```

However, as you can see, the row indices have been changed as well(6,5,4..). I want to keep them preserved, as before (1,2,3...).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just clear the row names after you grab the new data frame:

```
res <- result[match(ord, result$id),]
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#   id nobs
# 1 30  932
# 2 29  711
# 3 28  475
# 4 27  338
# 5 26  586
# 6 25  463
```